# Automatically fake missing modules

Tags: python

I want to fake a called module in Python to avoid the import errors within third-party modules. My code only imports these modules without running any code, so I should be fine.

I'd like to return `None` for every `ImportError`. Here's an example:

```py
# requests is installed, so it will return requests normally
import requests

# module `something` doesn't exists, instead of raising ImportError, return None
from something import a, b
```

This would be equivalent to creating a file called `something.py` with the following content:

```py
a = None
b = None
```

The thing is, I don't want to create such a file for each missing import, and just handle all possible missing modules that way.

Is it even possible? I've tried to override `import` statement, but it doesn't seem possible.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to provide a fallback for a module other than a `try/except` clause:

```
try:
    from something import a,b
except ImportError:
    a = None
    b = None
```